# Data Scraping using JSoup?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get data from this web site with web scraping.
http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx
[image]

I used JSoup before for more static HTML sites, but this one is difficult  for me because before I get the HTML table on the site have to click one button and I don't know if it's possible to use JSoup to manipulate the button.

After click this button I get a HTML table.

So How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrape data from website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803854/scrape-data-from-website)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've used JSoup as a html parser but not as a request/response handler. 
I'll give you two options:

Option 1:

- Figure out what's happening when you press that button. A button usually is just a POST request, so get info of that POST request (Google chrome dev tools is your friend).
- Emulate that POST using the JSoup [Connect interface](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) (check the POST method)
- Parse the html code with JSoup as you already know

Option 2:

- User a proper tool to handle a browser instance (for example [Selenium Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)) and perform whatever action you want in your webpage (fill forms, submit....).
- Once you are in the webpage that you want, get html code and use it with JSoup to extract your info.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the page has many input tags, Like a text input and a password, I'm guessing you know this. Now you have to pass data("name here","value here").post() that will manipulate a button.

Example: suppose this is the html code  `<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="submit" VALUE="SUBMIT" ALIGN = "center">`

then this would be your automating command!

```
Jsoup.connect("<url here>").userAgent("Chrome").data("submit","SUBMIT").post();
```