# scrape data from website?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

Hi i am trying to scrape data of a  site     i did code for that  i want to scraoe data on button click event  but when i run my program it throws exception

Exception is:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

How can i remove this exception and  work  my program

Here is my code which i tried

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class GetData {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // select barge
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");
        // click button
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //get only table tex
        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.className("grid-view"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you..

```
    //select barge
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");

    String sDate = "12/04/2014"; //What date you want
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
    String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
    // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
    System.out.println(htmlTableText);
```

Comment: how can i get genrated  web page?

Comment: Sorry I forget the **;** `String sDate = "12/04/2014";` With these fixing it is working.. I tried..

Comment: Use `String.split(" ")`. Split by <space>; `String arrRowData[] = htmlTableText.split("\n"); for(int i = 0; i < arrRowData.length(); i++){ String arrCellData[] = arrRowData[i].split(" "); for(int j = 0; j < arrCellData.length(); j++) { sout(arrCellData[j]);}}`

Comment: dear can u tell me without opneing browser how can i get same data

Comment: Try **HtmlUnitDriver**

Comment: Put `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);` or what ever your firefox version instead of `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` Table data layout may be bit different. Hope you can figure it out..In-case to debug put `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` after `driver.get(sURL);`

Comment: i made change but throwing exception

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139151/htmlunitdriver-does-not-appear-to-be-loading-page